# Printing rectangular that hollow in the middle, using user input and for loops

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, user-input, python-3.6

-My first objective is to print:-

```
*** 
* * 
***
```

What i have tried:

```
num = int(input("Enter the size"))

for x in range(1, num+1):
    for y in range(num):
        if (y==0 or y==num) or (x==0 or x==num):
            print("*", end= "")
        else:
           print(end= "")
    print()
```

Result when i input 3 as the num:

```
*
*
***
```

Please fix my code so i can get the right result for the first objective.

-My second objective is the code also have to be able to print like this if i input 4 in the num :-

```
**** 
*  * 
*  * 
****
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

A more "[pythonic](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/style/)" version of your code:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    num = int(input("Enter the size "))

    print('*'*num)
    for i in range(num-2):
        print('*'+' '*(num-2)+'*')
    print('*'*num)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your original code nearly works! Here it is with some small modifications that make it do what you want.

The first problem is that you seemed confused about what ranges x and y could take. If you are looping over range(num) then the counter in the loop will be between zero and `num - 1` and the loop will be executed `num` times. So 0 is the first iteration and `num - 1` is the last (so, the sides of the square).

The second problem is that you need to be printing a space character rather than just nothing in the else clause.

Here's the fixed version:

```
num = int(input("Enter the size"))

for x in range(num):
    for y in range(num):
        if (y==0 or y==num-1) or (x==0 or x==num-1):
            print("*", end= "")
        else:
            print(" ", end= "")
    print()
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation